# Misused mke2fs and cannot boot into system

Tags: linux, grub

I installed ubuntu with wubi in windows7 64bit, and I had installed Mandriva 2011 with a disk. I tried to learn linux with Ubuntu and misused mke2fs; after I reboot my computer, windows7 and ubuntu has crashed.
As I have mandriva, I boot into mandriva and found

```
# df -h

/dev/sda7 12G 9.8G 1.5G 88% /
/dev/sda2 15G 165M 14G 2% /media/logical
/dev/sda6 119G 88G 32G 74% /media/2C9E85319E84F51C
/dev/sda5 118G 59G 60G 50% /media/D25A6DDE5A6DBFB9
/dev/sda9 100G 188M 100G 1% /media/ae69134a-a65e-488f-ae7f-150d1b5e36a6
/dev/sda1 100M 122K 100M 1% /media/DELLUTILITY
/dev/sda3 98G 81G 17G 83% /media/OS

# fdisk /dev/sda
Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xd24f801e

Device Boot Start End Blocks Id System
/dev/sda1 2048 206847 102400 6 FAT16
/dev/sda2 * 206848 30926847 15360000 7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3 30926848 235726847 102400000 7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4 235728864 976771071 370521104 f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5 235728896 481488895 122880000 7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6 727252992 976771071 124759040 7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda7 481500243 506674034 12586896 83 Linux
/dev/sda8 506674098 514851119 4088511 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda9 514851183 727246484 106197651 83 Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

I think I may used the following command

```
mke2fs -j -L "logical"/dev/sda2
```

but I had forgotten what kind of partition it was before I transfered it into ext3

Data was not lost, and I can view my files as I could in Windows
In Mandriva, there are following disks;
117.2G hard disk, files in it is the same as my Windows D:, and ubuntu was installed in it；119.0G hard disk is my G:, with my personal files in it;12.0G is the same with mandriva / (with means root), 101.3G hard disk with nothing but lost+found;DELLUTILITY should be Dell computer utilities preinstalled in my computer ;logical is the disk which I had spoiled；and OS is the C: in my Windows.

After I boot, grub let me choose Mandriva or Windows. I chose windows and it tells me:FILE system type unknown, partition type 0x7
Error 13: Invalid or unsupported executable format
I doubt something wrong with ubuntu grub

```
# cat /boot/grub/menu.lst
timeout 5
color black/cyan yellow/cyan
gfxmenu (hd0,6)/boot/gfxmenu
default 0

title linux
kernel (hd0,6)/boot/vmlinuz BOOT_IMAGE=linux root=UUID=199581b7-ac7e-4c5f-9888-24c4f213cad8 nokmsboot logo.nologo quiet resume=UUID=34c546e4-9c42-4526-aa64-bbdc0e9d64fd splash=silent vga=788
initrd (hd0,6)/boot/initrd.img

title linux-nonfb
kernel (hd0,6)/boot/vmlinuz BOOT_IMAGE=linux-nonfb root=UUID=199581b7-ac7e-4c5f-9888-24c4f213cad8 nokmsboot resume=UUID=34c546e4-9c42-4526-aa64-bbdc0e9d64fd
initrd (hd0,6)/boot/initrd.img

title failsafe
kernel (hd0,6)/boot/vmlinuz BOOT_IMAGE=failsafe root=UUID=199581b7-ac7e-4c5f-9888-24c4f213cad8 nokmsboot failsafe
initrd (hd0,6)/boot/initrd.img

title windows
root (hd0,1)
makeactive
chainloader +1
```

I can boot into linux, but not ubuntu, it boot into Mandriva

I dont have a boot disk

Help me find a way to make it work again, Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is the wrong place for this kind of question. Try on http://askubuntu.com.

Comment: @terdon, as you can see, it was posted on stackoverflow when I commented. Of course, that was not the right place.

Comment: Sorry @Zagorax, my bad, saw both question and comment on SO and I thought the coment came after the migration. Deleting my comment to avoid confusion.